# Transposing a row to columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, split

I have imported this data into SQL Server from a flat file source.

```
B  01  1007282   Y  1001201 15102
B  02  LEVEL     Y  2705201 15102
B  03  1998014   Y  2808201 15102
B  05            Y  2808201 15102
B  06  49081100  Y  1708201 15102
B  07  64072151  Y  2903201 15102
B  08  75090350  Y  0111200 15102
B  09  58082950  Y  0608200 15102
B  10  75112551  Y  1007200 15102
B  11  72030950  Y  1007200 15102
B  20  74507632  Y  2808201 15102
B  23  98240166  Y  2808201 15102
B  25  U4507632  Y  2808201 15102
B  26  45002267  Y  2808201 15102
```

From this data I need to take each row and split each one into a different column:

```
Column 1 : B  01  1007282   Y  1001201 15102
Column 2 : B  02  LEVEL     Y  2705201 15102
...
```

Comment: Can you show the current table structure for the location where you imported this to? Is it really just one column? Is there a known number of rows? If there are 5,000 rows do you expect to pivot it into a table with 5,000 columns? WHY?

Comment: there is like 200 rows that i need to put into columns if that is possible please let me know

Comment: 200 columns is quite a lot. What are you going to do with the data then? Knowing the purpose will help us give you better answers. Yes we can show you how to do what you're doing but it doesn't sound like a good idea and it's very difficult to envision how you would use it.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Given no other changes, what makes scrolling horizontally easier than scrolling vertically to review this data? In fact if that is what you want to do I'd suggest pasting the rows into Excel and creating a pivot table - much easier to do there than in SQL IMHO (though @bluefeet might disagree).

Comment: Also what version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

This answer may become obsolete depending on further requirements, but given the comments thus far, my suggestion is to not change the data in SQL Server just to review it horizontally rather than vertically. Applications like Excel are much better suited to this. You can copy and paste the query result from Management Studio (results to grid), copy and paste from the source flat file, or otherwise get the data into Excel as a column. Highlight the 200 rows, hit `Copy`, then right-click somewhere and choose `Paste Special...` you will see a dialog here, simply check the `Transpose` checkbox and click `OK`. Voila, your rows are columns!

[image]

[image]

Sorry for the size. My retina doubles the size of all screen shots, and [I haven't found a *convenient* workaround yet, other than using a different computer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/84542/how-can-i-make-crisper-screen-shots-on-mbp-retina). :-(

---

Now, if you really want to do this in SQL Server, you could I suppose do something ugly like this. Given the following source table (and assuming SQL Server 2008 or better):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.InColumns(col VARCHAR(255));
GO

INSERT dbo.InColumns(col) VALUES
('B  01  1007282   Y  1001201 15102'),
('B  02  LEVEL     Y  2705201 15102'),
('B  03  1998014   Y  2808201 15102'),
('B  05            Y  2808201 15102'),
('B  06  49081100  Y  1708201 15102'),
('B  07  64072151  Y  2903201 15102'),
('B  08  75090350  Y  0111200 15102'),
('B  09  58082950  Y  0608200 15102'),
('B  10  75112551  Y  1007200 15102'),
('B  11  72030950  Y  1007200 15102'),
('B  20  74507632  Y  2808201 15102'),
('B  23  98240166  Y  2808201 15102'),
('B  25  U4507632  Y  2808201 15102'),
('B  26  45002267  Y  2808201 15102');
```

Now some oh so fun dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'', @maxlen INT;

SELECT @maxlen = MAX(LEN(col)) FROM dbo.InColumns;

SELECT @sql += N',
    Col' + RTRIM(rn) + ' VARCHAR(' + RTRIM(@maxlen) + ')'
 FROM (SELECT rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
  (ORDER BY col) FROM dbo.InColumns) AS x;

SET @sql = N'CREATE TABLE dbo.InRows
(' + STUFF(@sql, 1, 1, N'') + ');';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

SET @sql = N'';

SELECT @sql += N', 
  (SELECT col FROM x WHERE rn = ' + RTRIM(rn) + ')'
  FROM (SELECT rn = ROW_NUMBER() 
    OVER (ORDER BY col) FROM dbo.InColumns) AS x;

SET @sql = N';WITH x AS (SELECT col, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
   (ORDER BY col) FROM dbo.InColumns)
INSERT dbo.InRows SELECT TOP (1) '
  + STUFF(@sql, 1, 1, N'') + ' FROM x;';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
GO
SELECT * FROM dbo.InRows;
GO
DROP TABLE dbo.InRows;
```

Results:

```
Col1                               Col2   ...
---------------------------------  -------------------------
B  01  1007282   Y  1001201 15102  B  02  LEVEL     Y  27...
```

See why this is much easier in Excel?

With 200 rows, you're coming dangerously close to exceeding the max row size for a table. You could "fix" that by making these 200 `varchar(max)` columns, but the thought of that actually made me shudder.

Comment: Amazing that you would answer this question Aaron -- it seems to me the OP does not actually want to do this (because I can't imaging why).